# angularjs dygraph how to show only positive values?

Tags: angularjs, dygraphs

is there a way just to show positive values on my dygraph.. my Y and X axis start both at 0 ?

Is there a option I can add or I need to go trow customRange for y axis option and calculate each max/min per graph?

My options are:

```
var options = {
                        labels: labels,
                        showRangeSelector: true,
                        legend: 'always',
                        ylabel: units,
                        title: graphTitle,
                        includeZero: true,
                        axes: {
                            y: {
                                valueFormatter: function (value, opts, seriesName, dygraph, row, col) {
                                    if (seriesName == "Mode") {
                                        return modemMode[value];
                                    } else if (seriesName == "Submode") {
                                        return modemSubmode[value];
                                    } else if (seriesName == "Sysmode") {
                                        return modemSysmode[value];
                                    } else if (seriesName == "Roaming") {
                                        return modemRoaming[value];
                                    }
                                    return value;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g) {

                            for (var i=0; i<highlightArea.length; i++) {
                                var left = g.toDomXCoord(highlightArea[i][0]);
                                var right = g.toDomXCoord(highlightArea[i][1]);

                                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(217, 101, 87, 0.2)";
                                canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left, area.h);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`valueRange`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueRange) option to achieve this:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  valueRange: [0, null]  // null means "calculate max from the data"
});
```

Here's a [full example](https://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/10311/).